# How to show a bijection related to the cartesian product of orthogonal groups?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $O_{r,s} := \{M \in M_n \mid M^TI_{r,s}M = I_{r,s} \}$, where $I_{r,s} = diag(\underbrace{ 1,\ldots,1}_{\text{$r$ times}}, \underbrace{-1,\ldots,-1}_{\text{$s$ times}})$.
>
> Let further be $O(n)$ the usual orthogonal group on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $K_{r,s} := O(n) \cap O_{r,s}$ is compact and that there is a bijection with $O(r) \times O(s)$.

I have already shown that $O_{r,s}$ is a closed subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ regarding the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and that $O(n)$ is compact. And, if I am not mistaken, by the fact that the interseciton of a closed set and a compact set is compact we easily see that $K_{r,s}$ is indeed compact.

However, I do not quite get how the bijection part is supposed to work. I understand that we may identify $O(n)$ with $O_{n,0}$, but I do not see how to proceed here. Could you please give me a hint?

**Edit:** Thanks to CylcotomicField's hint I have progressed a bit: I understand now that for $A \in O(r), B \in O(s)$ holds that

$$\begin{bmatrix} A &0 \\ 0 &B \end{bmatrix} \in O(n)$$

and

$$\begin{bmatrix} A &0 \\ 0 &B \end{bmatrix} \in O_{r,s}.$$

If we could now show that for each $M \in K_{r,s}$ holds that

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} A &0 \\ 0 &B \end{bmatrix}$$

for some $A,B$ as above we would be done, but I do not see how to do this. Could you please give me another hint?

Comment: Consider $I_{r,s}$ as a block diagonal matrix with identity matrices $I_r$ and $-I_s$ on the diagonal and zero matrices in the off-diagonal blocks.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: I am sorry, but I do not quite get it yet, see my edit.